# inequality involving different points in the domain of convex function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Consider a convex function f and an interior point $x'$ of its domain $dom(f)$

Consider the following inequality:

$d^T x \leq d^T x'$ for $ \forall x \in  \ dom(f)$

Why can this only hold for $d=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Pick $x = x' + t d$ for $t > 0$ small enough. (And you should answer: Why is this possible?)

Comment: x' is an interior point, so there is an open ball centered at x' which  is contained in the domain of  f?

Comment: Yes, this is right.